# Avoiding redundant constraints when working with phantom types

Tags: haskell, ghc, gadt

This is a simplified, perhaps silly example of what I'm trying to code up (which is more complex and involves compile time encoding of list length).

Given the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data D (a :: Bool) where
  D :: Bool -> D a
```

I want the following function `g`:

```
g :: D a -> Bool
g (D x) = x == a
```

Of course this won't compile as `a` is a type, not a value.

Here's a possible solution:

```
class C (a :: Bool) where
  f :: D a -> Bool

instance C True where
  f (D x) = x == True

instance C False where
  f (D x) = x == False

g :: (C a) => D a -> Bool
g = f
```

But then I have to add a constraint to `g`, which seems redundant as `a :: Bool` and I've got instances for all cases of `Bool`.

Is there anyway I could write `g` such that it has the signature:

```
g :: D a -> Bool
```

i.e. doesn't require an additional constraint?

Comment: Part of the problem here is that Haskell erases types at runtime: even if 'g :: forall a. D a -> Bool` at runtime `g` is not passed the "value" of `a`. To circumvent that you need either a typeclass constraint (which passes a dictionary at runtime) or a singleton as shown below by dfeuer. Maybe in the future we will get `g :: pi a . ...` for non-erased types, but for now...

Comment: You can also think of this as `forall` always being parametric: the behavior of `g` cannot depend on the type `a`. `pi` would be the non-parametric counterpart to `forall`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've worked around this issue by providing separate constructors wherever I want to differentiate the types at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible, because I could hand you a perfectly good value of type `D Any`, where `Any` is defined

```
type family Any :: k where {}
```

What you can do is write a more generally useful class:

```
data SBool a where
  SFalse :: SBool 'False
  STrue :: SBool 'True

sBoolToBool :: SBool a -> Bool
sBoolToBool SFalse = False
sBoolToBool STrue = True

class KnownBool a where
  knownBool :: SBool a
instance KnownBool 'False where
  knownBool = SFalse
instance KnownBool 'True where
  knownBool = STrue
```

Of course, all this machinery is really overkill if you're not using the types for anything else.